# Adding an ItemCreating event to a ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview, itemtemplate

We are building an ASP.NET web app that displays test questions in a `ListView`. Each type of question (true/false, multiple choice, short answer, etc.) requires a different layout in HTML.

I've been studying [a post from Microsoft (see Figure 6)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/april/cutting-edge-listview-tips-and-tricks#code-try-18) which explains how to change the `<ItemTemplate>` of a `ListView` based on the data the template contains. Using the `OnItemCreated` event that fires at every item in the list, I can successfully change `ListView` item template according to the type of question being asked.

However, as the article states, "if you handle `ItemCreated` and set the `ItemTemplate` property there, the change will affect the next item, but not the item being currently processed." That's the issue: questions get an off-by-one template.

The article's solution is to override the `ListView` class to add a new event. That in itself is fine, but when using suggested code, the event `ItemCreating` does not fire. The author starts using `<x:ListView>` instead of `<asp:ListView>`, but he doesn't explain how ASP.NET is grabbing his custom `ListView` over the default one. Here is the relevant code that is supposed to override the `<asp:ListView>` and provide the `OnItemCreating` event:

```
/// <summary>
/// Override to allow a <c>ListView</c> to have multiple <c>ItemTemplate</c>s depending on the
/// type of item being data bound.
/// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/april/cutting-edge-listview-tips-and-tricks#S5
/// </summary>
public class ListView : System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView
{
   public event EventHandler<ListViewItemCreatingEventArgs> ItemCreating;

   private int mDisplayIndex;
   private bool mShouldInstantiate = false;

   protected override void InstantiateItemTemplate(Control container, int displayIndex)
   {
      if (mShouldInstantiate)
      {
         base.InstantiateItemTemplate(container, displayIndex);
         mShouldInstantiate = false;
      }
   }

   protected override ListViewDataItem CreateDataItem(int dataItemIndex, int displayIndex)
   {
      // Fire a NEW event: ItemCreating
      ItemCreating?.Invoke(this, new ListViewItemCreatingEventArgs(dataItemIndex, displayIndex));

      // Cache for later
      mDisplayIndex = displayIndex;

      // Call the base method
      return base.CreateDataItem(dataItemIndex, displayIndex);
   }

   protected override void OnItemCreated(ListViewItemEventArgs e)
   {
      base.OnItemCreated(e);

      mShouldInstantiate = true;
      InstantiateItemTemplate(e.Item, mDisplayIndex);
   }
}
```

How can I use my custom `ListView` with an added event, instead of the default `ListView` without the event?

I tried naming my overridden `ListView` with a different name, but it doesn't get recognized as a control. This may have something to do with the `<x:>` custom prefix, but someone more knowledgeable has to explain that clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Custom elements need their prefixes registered, like `<%@ Register TagPrefix="..." Namespace="..." %>`